# User authentication with XMLHttpRequest works in IE, not in Chrome?

Tags: authentication, twitter, webkit, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome

The following function works in IE but not in Chrome:

```
function doStuff() {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("POST", "http://twitter.com/statuses/update.json", true, "USERNAME-HERE", "PASSWORD-HERE");
  request.send("status=STATUS UPDATE HERE");
}
```

Chrome generates the following request.  Note the Authorization header is missing:

```
OPTIONS /statuses/update.json HTTP/1.1
Host: twitter.com
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/532.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/4.0.249.78 Safari/532.5
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: file://
Access-Control-Request-Headers: Content-Type
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

I get the following response (http 401):

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Wed, 03 Feb 2010 00:39:33 GMT
Server: hi
Status: 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Twitter API"
X-Runtime: 0.00107
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=300
Set-Cookie: _twitter_sess=BAh7BzoHaWQiJTUxMTc2Nzk4N2U0YzMzZmU0ZTQyNzI4NjQyYjI3ODE2Igpm%250AbGFzaElDOidBY3Rpb25Db250cm9sbGVyOjpGbGFzaDo6Rmxhc2hIYXNoewAG%250AOgpAdXNlZHsA--bb61324c3ba12c3cd1794b3895a906a69c154edd; domain=.twitter.com; path=/
Expires: Wed, 03 Feb 2010 00:44:33 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 73
Connection: close

{"request":"/statuses/update.json","error":"Could not authenticate you."}
```

So, how am I supposed to pass a username and password to XHR?  Webkit/Safari documentation says the open method should take these parameters, so I'm not sure why it is failing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was that I needed to add

```
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

The way I'm doing this is... special... so this may not be of much use to others going forward.  But once I added this webkit started adding Authorization.

Comment: glad request.setRequestHeader() was useful to you after all.

Comment: How did you get around the cross domain call?  Or does twitter respond to OPTIONS properly?

Comment: Cross domain was not an issue for me... because what I was doing was special.

Answer (score 3):

From the look of it, you're trying to do an X-Domain XMLHTTPRequest, which is why Chrome sends the OPTIONS pre-flight request. Because the Twitter server doesn't respond to the OPTIONS request indicating that X-Domain access is okay, you get a failure here.

Your code would only work in IE in the Local Computer zone, or if you turn off x-domain-checking (very dangerous)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'yourvalue');
```

Comment: That won't really help him. Note that Chrome is sending an OPTIONS request.

Comment: @EricLaw he still needs to set Authorization header.  And your answer is right too.

Comment: Adding Authorization doesn't help.

Comment: The authorization header will be automatically sent by the last two parameters of the Open() call.  If the Open() call wasn't x-domain.